# Turn off emojis in mail subject line

Tags: mail.app

I despise having emojis in the subject line of my emails (iOS and OSX); I find it an obnoxious distraction. Is there a way to turn the rendering of them off?

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about iOS or MacOS?  In MacOS you could in theory get rid of all emoji by removing the Apple Color Emoji font.  In iOS I don't think that's possible.  In any case, no way to be selective about it.

Comment: Yea I was referring to both. Bummer.